# VMWare Virtualized Applications and its Running Process instructions Tracing

Tags: process, operating-system, vmware, virtualization, instructions

I'm exploring on VMWare Virtualization Concept, and looking mainly on below two:

1) Is it possible to trace out instructions from a process running in Guest OS? if so
   a) How to trace, in the Guest OS itself  ?
   b) How to trace, at virtualization layer ?

Basically when a process is running in Guest OS in VMware env, how to trace the calls/instructions from the process in Guest OS ??

2) In a virtualized application is it possible to trace out instructions ?

Please provide any useful links on this..
im really appreciating your time on this ..
Thank you so much .. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the guest OS, just use your debugger (gdb?) as you would do on the host. Not sure to understand the question...
2. You can achieve tracing of the virtualized guest with [Qemu and GDB](http://files.meetup.com/1590495/debugging-with-qemu.pdf). I am not aware of such things with WMWare (at least Player).